# How to display current manu on wordpress page display parent and sub-menu fo on sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a main navigation and all parents have children.

Example:
Parent Page A:

- Child A1
  - Child A11
  - Child A12
    - Child A12
  - Child A13
- Child A2
- Child A3

Parent Page B:

- Child B1
  - Child B11
  - Child B12
    - Child B12
  - Child B13
- Child B2

If we are click on Child A12, sidebar should looks like:
Parent Page A:

- Child A1
  - Child A11
  - Child A12
    - Child A12
  - Child A13
- Child A2
- Child A3

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple CSS tweak! use firebug see the class being added to the child and sub-child menus and accordingly write the css!